# Sentry does not show tastypie errors messages

Tags: python, django, tastypie, sentry

I'm using Django with tastypie, and Sentry for error tracking.

The problem is the errors raised for tastypie are not logging the error message.

They are logged with the message:

```
core.api.api_user.hydrate
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/test/123/
```

and should log the next message:

```
core.api.api_user.hydrate
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

and the rest of the Stacktrace.

this is my project logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request.tastypie': {
            "handlers": ["sentry"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": False
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Some idea how can i log better my errors?

django 1.4
Tastypie 0.9.11
sentry 3.5.7

Answer (score 0):

I have almost exactly the same setup as you and it works great. What i have different:

1. Sentry 4.7.9, could be that
2. I do not have explicit tastypie logger in settings, because tastypie already logs to ERROR, which is processed by sentry handler.
3. I keep my server on DEBUG=False. With DEBUG=True, tastypie will not log anything, just spit error message in response.

Answer (score 0):

Even by logging everything on DEBUG, I see no Sentry logs with these 500 errors.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
```

So, in `settings.py` `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` I replaced the `raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.Sentry404CatchMiddleware` with `myproduct.middleware.SentryCatchMiddleware` with the following implementation:

```
from raven.contrib.django.models import client
from raven.contrib.django.middleware import Sentry404CatchMiddleware
import logging

class SentryCatchMiddleware(Sentry404CatchMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code >= 500:
            data = client.get_data_from_request(request)
            data.update({
                'level': logging.ERROR,
                'logger': 'http500',
            })
            result = client.captureMessage(message='Internal Server Error: %s' % request.build_absolute_uri(), data=data)
            request.sentry = {
                'project_id': data.get('project', client.project),
                'id': client.get_ident(result),
            }
            return response
        return super(SentryCatchMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
```

I would love to see a better solution though!

Comment: Hmmm. On production the errors are logged twice now. So it's True: `DEBUG=True` means the django.request.tastypie are not logged.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tastypie setting **[TASTYPIE_FULL_DEBUG](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-full-debug)**. With Sentry/Raven if you set **TASTYPIE_FULL_DEBUG** to **True**, it will log exceptions and the core **DEBUG** setting will control what the output is.